# cordova project html files getting restore after installing plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to know one thing. When I install cordova project it has a default index.html page in assets folder. It's ok but after I changing code in index.html file, if i want to install any plugin in that project, every time index.html getting restore to default code. I can't understand why this is happening.

If this is a process of cordaova then I've to install all require plugins at first then I can continue the project. But in progress may be I need to install plugins so how can I keep my code safely in app project?
This is a major thing to me. Please give me a proper way

Comment: No that is not at all, We need to make changes in index.html file under www folder and it never reverted on plugin install.Are using any utility to build app  like gulp or grunt?

Comment: I'm using android studio. and installing plugins by CLI

Comment: Add plugin using cordova cli, then build project using cordova cli(cordova build android), then open platforms\android folder in android studio to generate signed build. You can also install android build in device using cordova cli

Comment: yes. every time I'm using cordova cli to build(cordova build android). but still cant get the main point of revert pages

Comment: can you put project structure?

Comment: my index file is here  D:\myapp\platforms\android\assets\www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not manipulate `index.html` file present under `platform\android folder` as this folder will be rebuilt every time when you build the android platform. You gotta make changes in `index.html` present under `D:\myapp\www` folder which gets copied to the respective platforms when you build them.

**UPDATE:** You can directly edit the contents in platform\android folder and run the same for testing. But the moment you build it using cordova build android command, the contents from root folder gets copied to platform folder. Even if you directly manipulate contents under platform folder, you still gotta merge the changes back to root folder

Comment: if I work in index.html under D:\myapp\www folder then how its possible to run the project in android studio?

Comment: @BubaiDas You can directly edit the contents in platform\android folder and run the same for testing. But the moment you build it using cordova build android command, the contents from root folder gets copied to platform folder. Even if you directly manipulate contents under platform folder, you still gotta merge the changes back to root folder. Better use cordova CLI

Comment: @BubaiDas My pleasure.Please accept the answer and upvote it so that it will be useful for others too. Happy coding